# Reformat array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to reformat this array of objects:

```
let users = [{
        Username: "test1",
        Attributes: [{
            Name: "sub",
            Value: "1234"
        }, {
            Name: "email",
            Value: "test1@gmail.com"
        }]
    },
    {
        Username: "test2",
        Attributes: [{
            Name: "sub",
            Value: "5678"
        }, {
            Name: "email",
            Value: "test2@gmail.com"
        }]
    },
]
```

I want to reformat to this:

```
users: [{
            Username: "test1",
            sub: "1234",
            email: "test1@gmail.com}, {
                    Username: "test2",
                    sub: "5678",
                    email: "test2@gmail.com}]
```

How to reformat this array of the object? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map` to loop thru the array. Use `reduce` to summarize the `Attributes` array into an object.

```js
let users = [{"Username":"test1","Attributes":[{"Name":"sub","Value":"1234"},{"Name":"email","Value":"test1@gmail.com"}]},{"Username":"test2","Attributes":[{"Name":"sub","Value":"5678"},{"Name":"email","Value":"test2@gmail.com"}]}]

let result = users.map(({Username,Attributes}) => {
  let a = Attributes.reduce((c, v) => ({ ...c,[v.Name]: v.Value}), {});
  a.Username = Username;
  return a;
});

console.log(result);
```

Shorter Version:

```
let result = users.map(({Username, Attributes})=>({Username,...Attributes.reduce((c,v)=> ({...c, [v.Name]: v.Value}) ,{})}));
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to map each original `object` to a new one. Inside the `map()` you can traverse the `Attributes` array to add properties into the new `object` that will be returned.

```js
let users =[
  {
    Username: "test1",
    Attributes:[
      {Name: "sub", Value:"1234"},
      {Name:"email", Value:"test1@gmail.com"}
    ]
  },
  {
    Username: "test2",
    Attributes: [
      {Name: "sub", Value:"5678"},
      {Name:"email", Value:"test2@gmail.com"}
    ]
  }
];

let res = users.map(({Username, Attributes}) =>
{
    let newObj = {Username};    
    Attributes.forEach(({Name, Value}) => newObj[Name] = Value);
    return newObj;
});

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through the users using `for...of`. Loop trough the `Attributes` to convert each object with 2 properties to a key-value pair. Create a merged object using [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```js
const users=[{Username:"test1",Attributes:[{Name:"sub",Value:"1234"},{Name:"email",Value:"test1@gmail.com"}]},{Username:"test2",Attributes:[{Name:"sub",Value:"5678"},{Name:"email",Value:"test2@gmail.com"}]}];

const output = [];

for(const { Username, Attributes } of users) {
  const attributes = Attributes.map(({ Name, Value }) => ({ [Name]: Value }));
  output.push(Object.assign({ Username }, ...attributes))
}

console.log(output)
```